# Google Map Custom Overlay with INPUT text not working on IE Edge

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, custom-overlay

When using [Google Map Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) to add pop over with input text boxes as seen below, when I try to click on the input box on IE Edge 15 (Haven't tested on other IE versions) I can't click on it and start typing as if it won't set focus on the input box.

It does works on Chrome though.

```
CustomMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var self = this;
  var div = this.div;
  if (!div) {
    // Generate marker html
    div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'custom-marker';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.innerHTML = '<span><input type="text" value="asfd" style="padding:10px;font-size:18px;" /></span>';
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'custom-marker-inner';

    div.appendChild(innerDiv);

    if (typeof(self.args.marker_id) !== 'undefined') {
      div.dataset.marker_id = self.args.marker_id;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
    });

    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
  }
};
```

[Full example code here - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zx5xa2u/10/)

I am wondering if my implementation above is wrong or this is a bug from Google Map? [Edit: or is there a work around?]

Comment: My guess is would be a bug in IE rather than the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle. It might be a bit hacky, but I've updated the click event to focus on the input:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
    event.target.focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ng4hxqfs/5/

Comment: Thanks, but in my real life production environment, there will be more than one input text boxes.

Comment: That should still work then? The div is within the scope of the marker and I'm not getting all inputs, just the ones on the marker current marker being clicked.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle multiple inputs. The styling is a off but proves it should work.

Comment: Quickly tested, it works, will try again tomorrow morning.